Cannot install pip install expliot in python - Building wheel for bluepy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.│ exit code: 1
enter image description hereWhen I try to install pip install expliot package via cmd in windows machine, I get 2 errors names ×
Building wheel for bluepy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1 

**AND**
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Working dir is C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-obmlo0fl\bluepy_ccde389d63414d1ba621ba01bad043dd
      execute make -C ./bluepy clean
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

Any idea on how to solve this?
Need to install "pip install expliot" package by www.expliot.in in a windows machine through CMD.

According to PyPi expliot package supports only POSIX :: Linux Operating System but you are using Windows.
There don't seem to be any support for Windows. See the docs.
